# Play a soundfile after downloading from a url

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, webclient

I am downloading an audio file and storing it in byte[] iin a c# Wpf project

```
byte[] audio = client.DownloadData(new Uri("http://static.sfdict.com/dictstatic/dictionary/audio/luna/E03/E0397400.mp3"))
```

How do i play this sound file.

Comment: Why download first? MediaPlayer.Open takes an Uri argument.

Comment: Thanx for the help. Lemme try this and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
byte[] audio = client.DownloadData(new Uri("http://static.sfdict.com/dictstatic/dictionary/audio/luna/E03/E0397400.mp3"))
System.IO.Stream s = new MemoryStream(audio);
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(s);
player.Play();
```

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to support `wav` files only.

Comment: Nopz this one is not working, it says incorrect heade. Cuz the file is in mp3 format